# Find rows with certain combination of values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
iso_o iso_d FLOW FLOW_0 
  185   190   NA     NA         
  185   190   NA     NA         
  185   190   NA     NA  
  185   190    1     NA         
  185   190   NA     NA 
  185   190   NA   4249            
  185   114    1     NA
```

Now I want to know which rows and the number of rows that have for example "185" in iso_o and "190" in iso_d.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `which(data$iso_o == 185 & data$iso_d == 190)`?

Comment: i knew it was easy but just didnt get it. Thanks, this works!

Comment: @r.user.05apr would be a good idea to post your comment as an answer and OP should accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `subset`

```
> subset(df, iso_o == 185 & iso_d == 190)
  iso_o iso_d FLOW FLOW_0
1   185   190   NA     NA
2   185   190   NA     NA
3   185   190   NA     NA
4   185   190    1     NA
5   185   190   NA     NA
6   185   190   NA   4249
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index with the `which`-function:

```
which(data$iso_o == 185 & data$iso_d == 190)
```

Using brackets might make it a bit easier to read:

```
which( (data$iso_o == 185) & (data$iso_d == 190) )
```